# Python - searching for letters in a list of words

Tags: python, list

I am absolutely new to programming atm. I have searched the forums but none of the results were applicable to my case (unless I am mistaken, but trust me the first thing I did was to google). Please help me if you have time.

Write a python program that prompts the user to enter a list of first names and stores them in a list. The program should display how many times the letter 'a' appears within the list.

Now I thought I have got the PERFECT code. But everytime the program only counts the number of "a"s in the first word on the list!?

```
terminate = False
position = 0
name_list = [ ]

while not terminate:
    name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
    name_list.append(name)

    response = input('Add more names? y/n: ')
    if response == 'n':
        terminate = True
        print(name_list)
        for t in name_list:
            tally = name_list[position].count('a')
            position = position + 1
        print("The numer of 'a' is: ", tally)
```

If anyone has time to help I would appreciate it.

Comment: 1. You loop twice over the items in your name list (more accurately: squared). 2. You forget to add up tally's.

Comment: 3. You could untagle your two loops (while terminate is false, you won't enter the response `if`) or even remove the `for` completely, and just count the letters a in last word (and add it to the total).

Comment: Not in the first. In the last!

Comment: Too different from OP's code, but I would settle for `print (''.join(name_list).count('a'))`

Comment: @usr2564301 : I would have suggested that, but I'm not sure of the efficientcy of concatenating all strings just to count letters : maybe use an `iterator.chain` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. you meant to use `tally` as an accumulator but are actually not adding to it.
2. You don't need the `position` indexer, `for t in name_list` already iterates over all names in the list, at each iteration of the for loop `t` is a name from `name_list`.

fix the inner loop

```
terminate = False
# position = 0 <-- this is not needed anywhere
name_list = [ ]

while not terminate:
    name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
    name_list.append(name)

    response = input('Add more names? y/n: ')
    if response == 'n':
        terminate = True
        print(name_list)
        tally = 0  # initialise tally
        for t in name_list:
            tally += t.count('a')  # increment tally
    print("The numer of 'a' is: ", tally)
```

Comment: You don't need the `terminate` variable either, nor the for loop (since you can increment the total after each word)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not fully understandable to me. Probably, because some stuff is missing. So, I am assuming, you already have the list of names. In the code you presented, you are overwriting `tally` each time you count the number of a in a name in the list. Besides other possible bugs in your code (maybe when creating the list of names - I'd use a while-loop for this), you should write

`tally += name_list[position].count('a')`
which equals

`tally = tally + name_list[position].count('a')`

instead of your

`tally = name_list[position].count('a')`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get rid of the for loop, and position counter. If you want the total of all `'a'`, you have to sum `tally` for all the names :

```
terminate = False
name_list = []
total = 0

while "Adding more names":
    name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
    name_list.append(name)

    tally = name.count('a')
    total += tally
    print("The numer of 'a' in current name is: ", tally)

    if input('Add more names? y/n: ') == 'n':
        break
print(name_list)
print("The numer of 'a' is: ", total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
terminate = False
position = 0
name_list = [ ]
tally = 0
while not terminate:
    name = str(input('Please enter name: '))
    name_list.append(name)

    response = input('Add more names? y/n: ')
    if response == 'n':
        terminate = True
        print(name_list)
        for t in name_list:
            #tally = name_list[position].count('a')
            tally += name_list[position].count('a')
            position = position + 1
        print("The numer of 'a' is: ", tally)
```

initilize tally=0 and insted of "tally = name_list[position].count('a')" use "tally += name_list[position].count('a')" if you have to count "a" in entire list you have to update the tally value